# Django html dependencies

Tags: django, django-views

I'm new to Django, I'm trying to load bootstrap5 and js to my project. To achieve this, I created a 'base.html' under templates and extend it in my other html file. For example:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="mt-4"> 
  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This method works but I think it might make the maintenance harder if I include those tags in all of my html files, so is it possible to remove those tags and the dependencies still works?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried to use a document_processors to load the CDN, I can confirm that this method is executed but the style is still not loaded if I remove the tags.

```
# document.processor.py
def base_template_variables(request):
    return {
        'title': 'Default Title',
        'bootstrap_css_cdn': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'bootstrap_js_cdn': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    }
```